# MVC4 WebApi Controller Post Action with Dispose Pattern causes Multiple Actions Found Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dispose

I think I've spotted a problem with the MVC4 WebApi Controller in conjunction with the Dispose Pattern. The problem is with the Post Action Method, the response is a description of the Exception:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request:
Void Post(System.String) on type MVC4Api.Controllers.ValuesController
Void Dispose() on type MVC4Api.Controllers.ValuesController
```

The dispose pattern is sourced from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P). I've reduced the problem to just the boiler plate code below. Its worth pointing out that this problem does not occur with the Get method, I have confirmed it only with the Post method. Please try it out by Posting to the path `/api/values`.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    private bool _disposed;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        base.Dispose(disposing);

        if (disposing)
        {
            // dispose of dependencies
        }
    }

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

My question is how can I call the Post Method? And what is causing this problem?

**EDIT:**
As the error is about routing I have added below the WebApiConfig which controls the routing. This is loaded as normal at start up in the Global.asax and has not changed since starting a new WebApi project.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question you need answered?

Comment: Yes, how can I call the Post Method? And why does this happen?

Comment: The error is saying you have multiple post actions with that signature. Is what you posted the entire class?

Comment: Its the entire class. The route config involved is just the out-of-the-box created when opening a new MVC4 WebApi project. I'll post it for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its much easier to understand the solution when you correctly interpret the error message: When making the choice to the request, the WebApi Action Selector cannot decide between the `Dispose()` and `Post()` methods. (Which seems pretty daft in itself). So the error is effectively asking us to help make this decision for it.

My preferred option is to use the `NonActionAttribute` class on the `Dispose()` Action method. This is a clear and transparent instruction to the Action Selector to not consider the Dispose method in deciding where to route the request.

```
[NonAction]
public new void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

The other option is to change the accessor of the `Dipose()` method to `protected`, but that's just not as obvious.